# Azure Storage & Snapshots

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have a VHD in a container which was mounted by an instance (a DotNetNuke accelerator). But now the instance is stopped so the VHD is not mounted anymore.

The problem is I can't rename this VHD with any UI client. "CloudBerry Explorer for Azure Blob Storage" shows an error when I try to rename it of

> This operation is not permitted because the blob has snapshots.

I tried to list snapshots in VisualStudio but it only returns the blob's name...

I tried to mount the VHD in an instance and create a file and it works!?

I'm going crazy. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is accurate.  If you get that, it means the blob actually has snapshots.  When you mount a blob you are most likely mounting the current version and not a past snapshot.  You can enumerate the snapshots using the [REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd135734.aspx) (use the 'include=snapshots option) to prove this to yourself.

If you really want to delete the blob with minimal hassle, I would suggest using https://www.myazurestorage.com (safe site from Microsoft DPE).  It will enumerate your snapshots automatically and allow you to delete them.  Once they are all deleted, you can also delete the blob.

Comment: Sadly that site no longer works and its replacement (http://storageexplorer.com/) doesn't support deleting blobs with snapshots

Answer (score 17):

I've managed to remove blob which has snapshots by using Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer. Steps are:

1. You navigate to the blob in question
2. Right click -> Manage Snapshots
3. Delete all the snapshots and the blob will disappear also

Comment: This should be the accepted answer (on 2019 at least)

Comment: Tried it. There is no "Manage Snapshots" option for me

Comment: Solution for me was to delete it via azure portal. I got a popup asking whether I want also to delete blob snapshot, for which I responded with "Yes". was done in 1 sec.